# how can i remove %26 and %3D in MVC route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sorting

I have an MVC site project.
I have in the controller actionresult a class for search

```
public ActionResult Index(SearchModel search, int? pageNumber, string sortOrder)

public int? Year {get;set;}
        public String[] Status {get;set;}
        public DateTime? Start {get;set;}
        public DateTime? End {get;set;}
```

Performing a sort on a table in my view with action link i get the symbols
%26 and %3D

I perform this code

```
@Html.ActionLink("year", "Index", new
                                       {
                                           sortOrder = ViewBag.Year,
                                           Year = Request.QueryString["year"],
                                           Status = string.Join("&Status=", statusSelected.Select(x => x)),
                                           start=  Request.QueryString["start"],
                                           end=  Request.QueryString["end"]
                                       },
                                         new { title = "sort by year" })
```

how can i solve

thks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved so

```
<a href="@(Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { year=ViewBag.Year....})
```

+  (string.Join("&status=", statusSelected.Select(x => Url.Encode(x.tostring()))">year

In short i concatenate the url

It works but pheraps it is dirty
Ps i wrote by hand the code and couldcbe wrong
I hope helps someone

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the standard parameter binding failed to apply properly on the default `RouteValueDictionary` as you're manually generate the query string in this case as follows:-

```
string.Join("&Status=", statusSelected.Select(x => x))
```

I believe you've already know that URL strings are encoded by default and therefore the characters in `Status` — "&" and "=" get encoded to "%26" and "%3D" respectively.

Therefore one of the alternative would be changing your `SearchModel.cs`'s `Status` to accept `String` instead of `String[]` and convert back to String array manually:-

```
Status = string.Join(",", statusSelected.Select(x => x))
```

```
var statusList = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(search.Status).Split(',');
```

I've to admit this is a **quick & dirty** solution since it's the easiest workaround without using custom data binder.

Comment: Tks a lot for reply